# Which reporting services can consume Odata as a data source?

Tags: report, reporting, datasource, odata

I've developed an OData API which contains data collected by our users. Some of those users want to create their own reports based on this data via some 3rd party reporting package. I noticed that Telerik Reports can Access Odata APIs.

So my question is: Are there any other reporting packages which can also do this? Perhaps even some free solution?

Thanks,

Adrian